# How to reduce the problem to apply EVT

Tags: calculus, continuity, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the following condition ($\star$) for the real-valued continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$

($\star$) For any positive real number $R$, the following set is bounded.

$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |\, |f(x,y)| \leq R \}$

Answer the following questions.

1. Give an example of a continuous function $f$  that satisfies the condition ($\star$) and show that it satisfies ($\star$)
2. When the continuous function $f$ satisfies the condition ($\star$) show that one of the following holds

- $f$ has a maximum value but no minimum value
- $f$ has a minimum value but no maximum value

Answer: My idea is the following but I don't feel that it is correct or enough.

The example of $f$

$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} \qquad \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$

$\bigg|\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\bigg| \leq 1 \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad  \text{since}\,\, \,\,x^2+y^2 \geq 0 \,\,\,\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

So the example is satisfied the condition ($\star$) for all $R\geq 1$

We can see that if and only if $x=0$ and $y=0$, $f(x,y)$ attains its absolute maximum and for all other $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ the value of the function is less than 1. The range of the function is $(0,1]$. Therefore there is no global minimum and the global maximum value is 1.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Your function $\frac{1}{1 + x^2 + y^2}$ satisfies the opposite of the desired condition:  The set of all $(x,y)$ such that $|f(x,y)|\leq 1$ is equal to the entire plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and hence is not bounded.

Comment: @Michael I am sorry I didn't get that

Comment: Take $R=1$.  Then $$\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \left|\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\right| \leq 1\right\} = \mathbb{R}^2$$ And $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not bounded.

Comment: Why are you saying that hence it is not bounded?

Comment: Do you agree that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not bounded?

Comment: Yes I do but the function's value is in the interval $[0,1]$. Ok domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ so it is not bounded

Comment: Yes.  So your example for part 1 needs to change.  The part 2 of this problem is interesting and uses the fact that we are in the 2-d plane, that is, this is a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  The part 2 might fail if we only considered continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (such as the function $f(x)=x$).

Comment: @Michael Sorry for bothering you, in wiki a function $f$ defined on some set $X$ with real or complex values is called bounded if the set of its values is bounded. In other words, there exists a real number $M$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in X$. So in my example, the function's domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the range is (0,1]. So we can say this $R\geq 1$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, please tell where am I wrong? which part

Comment: They are not talking about a bounded function, they are talking about bounded sets.  The  *only* functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that have property $\star$ are *unbounded functions*.  A function with property $\star$ satisfies, for all positive real numbers $R$, a certain property.  A particular positive real number is $1$. However, your function does not satisfy the desired property for $R=1$. So your function does not satisfy property $\star$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for the explanation could you please give me an example for $f(x,y)$

Comment: We can have a version of property $\star$ for functions on 1-d domains, and the function  $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x$ satisfies that:  For all $c>0$, the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: |x|\leq c\}$ is bounded.